# Make a Join Permanent

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcgis-engine

So I've been using a dynamic join (IRelQueryTable to attach a SQL query to a feature layer) but now I want to make a permanent (or semi-permanent) join. How do you go about doing this in ArcEngine code? Do I use IFeatureDataConverter? If I have feature layer is it possible to add the joined data directly to the feature layer? Can I create a new feature layer with the joined data and have it take the place of the original feature layer? Please point me in the correct direction.

Comment: Well the way you normally do it interactively is to export or copy the feature layer to a new feature class. I am not sure if there is a simple, clean way to do it in-place in ArcObjects, since you would have to modify the schema.

Comment: Maybe you can create a view/spatial view off the data and use that for your process.. programmatically with ArcObjects.